# How to resize label width in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, autolayout, autoresize

can anyone please tell me how to auto size label **width** to the text size, i would appreciate it if u could give me a way doing that in IB .. if there is not, please provide me an example of doing it by code ...

I have a subview of tableView in my viewController, and above that tableView there should be labels displaying the text in a cell clicked on and there is a long words, the user can select up to four cells .. and after the first line finishes - full of labels - a new line should start

so i need your help with the code of resizing the label width and how to move the next label so it begins right after the end of the previous one

thanx

Comment: Are you using auto layout? What code / settings have you tried and what did it do wrong?

Comment: @Wain i tried using no.of lines but it did extends the height .. also sizetofit() didnt help at all .. both of them extended the height not the width

Comment: @ThomasKilian i tried it before, it helps only with height not with the width